# How can I test a TextPainter?

Tags: flutter

I've written a class to handle custom text-wrapping but I'm not sure how to test it.  I'm trying to use Flutter's `testWidgets` method to create an instance of my outer class, pass it some text, and then evaluate the results.  There's a public class `PrecisionTextOverflow` whose build method is like so. The `_PrecisionTextPainter` handles the operation of parsing and painting the text.:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        new CustomPaint(
          painter: new _PrecisionTextPainter(
              mainText,
              mainTextStyle,
              mainAlignment,
              secondaryText,
              secondaryTextStyle,
              secondaryAlignment,
              lineWidth,
              linesToWrap),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Since `_PrecisionTextPainter` uses `TextPainters` rather than `Text` widgets to paint the actual text it seems like the [Finder "find text" method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_driver/CommonFinders/text.html) won't work for me.

I need a way to test what it is my _PrecisionTextPainter has painted.  How can I access its fields or the resulting painted text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We unfortunately don't have a good way to test painting currently.

It's high on our list of things we want to do. You can track progress here: 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3227

Comment: *3 years later* Any news ? :)

Comment: Yup, we support golden tests now. See for instance:

[Flutter: Golden tests — compare Widgets with Snapshots](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-golden-tests-compare-widgets-with-snapshots-27f83f266cea), [How to run Flutter Golden (Snapshot) tests with Codemagic CI/CD](https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-golden-tests-with-codemagic-cicd/), or [Golden Toolkit](https://pub.dev/packages/golden_toolkit).